# Help optimize this linq statement

Tags: c#, linq, automapper

Please help me optimize this linq statement for performance. There are about 4000 drivers to go through and the page times out.
I am rather new to Linq

```
tblDriver driver = Mapper.Map<Domain.Driver, tblDriver>(driverDto);

var entries = (from e in driver.tblDriverLogEntries
                where e.OccuredAt <= utcEnd &&
                e.OccuredAt >= utcViolationsStart &&
                e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Where(x => !x.RemovedAt.HasValue).Count() > 0
                select e).Union(
                    //previous amended status
                    (from e in driver.tblDriverLogEntries
                        where e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Where(s => !s.RemovedAt.HasValue).Count() > 0
                        && e.OccuredAt < utcViolationsStart
                        orderby e.OccuredAt descending
                        select e).Take(1).Union(
                            //next amended status
                            (from e in driver.tblDriverLogEntries
                                where e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Where(s => !s.RemovedAt.HasValue).Count() > 0
                                && e.OccuredAt > utcEnd
                                orderby e.OccuredAt ascending
                                select e)
                            )
                    );
```

Comment: You really should have written your subqueries separately then combined them at the end.  That should at least make it easier to manage.

Comment: Optoimize for what? readability, performance, memory consumption or something I've forgotten to list?

Comment: are you sure there's always at least one fullfilling: "where e.OccuredAt < utcViolationsStart" if not the code will fail at .Take(1)

Comment: That's a good point Rune FS. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
where e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Where(x => !x.RemovedAt.HasValue).Count() > 0
```

You are using `Count() > 0` when you should be using `Any()`: this will give you at least some speedup (occurs 3 times in your query):

```
 where e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Any(x => !x.RemovedAt.HasValue)
```

You also might want to pre-define and get the results for this query so you don't have to re-query 3 times, i.e:

```
var subset = (from e in driver.tblDriverLogEntries 
             where e.tblDriverStatusChanges.Any(x => !x.RemovedAt.HasValue)
             select e).ToList();

 var entries = (from e in subset 
                where e.OccuredAt <= utcEnd &&
                e.OccuredAt >= utcViolationsStart 
                select e).Union(
                //previous amended status
                (from e in subset
                 where e.OccuredAt < utcViolationsStart
                 orderby e.OccuredAt descending
                 select e).Take(1).Union(
                 //next amended status
                 (from e in subset
                  where e.OccuredAt > utcEnd
                  orderby e.OccuredAt ascending
                  select e)));
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I am in the process of optimizing linq but am afraid the problem may lie in how we are implementing the automapper.